# listbox not being populated in IE works in FF and Chrome

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Hello I am working in php and javascript and have code where a admin can select a name in a dropdown box and it pulls up the locations that name is associated with these are sales guys. Well it works fine in FF and Chrome but in IE the list box just goes blank. hopefully someone can help me out bosses here use IE

Brent

DROPDOWN and LIST code

```
<label for="firstname"><?php echo ADD_EDIT_SALESREP;?><span class="required">*</span></label>
<select name="sales_rep" id="sales_rep" onChange="findLocation2(this.value)">
<option value="">Select</option>
<?php
$sqlQry1 = "SELECT * FROM ".TABLE_PREFIX."_employee WHERE status='t' AND is_Deleted='N' ORDER BY employee_Id";
$sql_Show1 = $DBObject->db_query($sqlQry1);
while($catArr = $DBObject->db_fetch_array($sql_Show1)){
?>
<div align="center"><br />
<option value="<?php echo $catArr['employee_Id'] ?>"><?php echo SafeOutput($catArr['first_Name']) ?> <?php echo SafeOutput($catArr['last_Name']) ?></option>
</div>
<?php
}
?>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<br />
<p>
</select>
<div id="salesrloc">
<select name="salesr_loc" id="salesr_loc" title="Sales Rep Loc" size="5" multiple="multiple">
<option value="">Select</option>
</select>
<br />
```

Javascript

```
<script language="javascript">
dv = document.createElement('div'); // create dynamically div tag
dv.setAttribute('id',"details");
function findLocation2(category)
{
dv.innerHTML='<div id="salesrloc" style="width:auto; height:200px;"><img src="image/loading.gif"></div> <br>';
var url11 = "salesrep2.php";
var qry11="?sales_rep=" + category ;
var result1='salesr_loc';
var ajaxRequest; // The variable that makes Ajax possible!
try{
ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
} catch (e){
try{
ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
} catch (e) {
try{
ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
} catch (e){
alert("Your browser broke!");
return false;
}
}
}
ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){ //alert(ajaxRequest.responseText);
var a=ajaxRequest.responseText;
try{
document.getElementById('salesr_loc').innerHTML=ajaxRequest.responseText;
}catch(e){
dv.innerHTML=ajaxRequest.responseText;
}
}
}
ajaxRequest.open("POST", url11+qry11, true);
ajaxRequest.send(null);
} </script>
```

and Finally populate listbox php

```
<?php
include("mastersecure.php");
$emp_id = $_GET['sales_rep'];
$qry= "select * FROM ".TABLE_PREFIX."_location ls, ".TABLE_PREFIX."_customer cs WHERE loc_Salesrep = ".$emp_id." AND ls.customer_Id = cs.customer_Id";
$res = $DBObject->db_query($qry);
?>
<body onLoad="document.getElementById('salesr_loc').focus();">
<select name="salesr_loc[]" id="salesr_loc" title="Sales Rep Loc" size="5" multiple="multiple">
<?php
while($row=$DBObject->db_fetch_array())
{
?>
<option value="<?=$row["location_Id"]?>"><?=$row["customer_Name"]?>, <?=$row["location_Name"]?></option>
<?php
}
?>
</select>
</body>
```

Comment: OT, Your `<label>` is done incorrectly. It looks like `<label for="firstname">` should be `<label for="sales_rep">`

Comment: Your first block of code is code spaghetti.  Why do you have `<div>` and `<p>` and `<br />` inside a `<select>` tag? A lot of these tags aren't closed, and a lot of the tags are closed but they haven't even been started anywhere?

Comment: Learn jQuery - the AJAX call and also a DOM manipulation is done in very clean and clear way and it will surely work in all browsers with no need to optimize the pure JS per browser...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the IE does not support **.innerHTML** for `< select>` elements!!

```
<select name="salesr_loc" id="salesr_loc"
...
document.getElementById('salesr_loc').innerHTML=ajaxRequest.responseText;
```

instead, you must do it in a loop:

```
var d = document.getElementById('salesr_loc');
for(...) {
   d.options[x] = new Option(..);
}
```

Comment: Thank you this did work and will be marked as correct but is not the way I went. I used document.getElementById('salesr_loc').outerHTML=ajaxRequest.responseText; and it seemed to work fine  Thank you for the answer

Comment: tx. i might be wrong here but i think that "outerHTML" is IE specific, as many others sadly..

Comment: It works in FF as well and I am really the only one that uses multiple browsers everyone else here uses IE so kinda a win win would be better if it did not work in FF that way I would not have to keep up with the changes LOL